# Is it possible in VSC to detect if Zen Mode is enabled

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I making an extension that needs to know if Zen Mode is enabled. Is this possible using the API?

Comment: There's a `inZenMode` context key, but I think that would only help if you want to use this in some `when` condition.

Comment: hmm this seems to not exist in vscode. I found some private properties on the layout  service. I'm looking for something in the public API that I could use in my extension, but thanks for the tip any way

Comment: Yeah, I don't think that exists.

Answer (score 0):

There currently isn't an API that allows you to check for Zen Mode, however there is an [open issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/114741) in the Microsoft VSCode GitHub repository.